# Using Script Function In Googlesheets to remove all spaces from cells in a range

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, search, match, substitution

I have a sheet where in one colum i have series of values in the form of

```
7s 8d 9h

Ad 8h 2s

etc
```

I want to run a script that removes all the spaces from the cells in the column

so they end up with

```
7s8d9h

Ad8h2s
```

I have tried some of the scripts others have posted to no avail.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A; " "; ))
```

[image]